# Created and Modified by column settings

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

Is there any way to keep the old created by and modified by sections when you edit it. It doesn't necessarily have to show when viewing the list. I'm referring to the view you're taken to if you edit the item. It shows the crated by and modified by there, but it changes when a new person edits the item. I want to show all the past people who modified it.

Comment: is versioning not working for you?

Comment: explain further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preserve the last modified date by activating versioning on your list. Go to list settings -> Version Settings ->  Create a version each time you edit an item in this list.

After that when you select or edit/view an item you always have the option "Version History" where you can view all changes made to this list items when and the person who did it.

As already mentioned, the created by field will never change.

Answer (score 0):

Created By is never going to change

You need 1 extra Column *PreviousModifiedBy* and a Workflow which On Change adds the current Modifier to that field, preferably with a separator.

You then need CSR code (or something else JavaScript) on the Forms to change the footer to show previous Modifiers.